# Will .NET 2 application work on .NET 3?

Tags: .net

If I program an application designed for .NET 2 and then a computer with only .NET 3 installed launch the application - will it work?

I know there are some significant changes between the frameworks, such as obsolete methods and for example new features like LINQ (was it only 3.5?).

What if I have tested the code with .NET 3 and it works?

To describe what my situation is: I have both .NET 2 and .NET 3 on my PC - there are absolutely no problems when I click on "projects -> settings -> .NET 2" and then startwithoutdebugging. There are also absolutely no problems when i do projects -> settings -> .NET 3 and then start the app without debugging.

I just want to be sure that my application will run on any machine that has .NET >= 2.0.

Comment: Yes - .NET 3 and .NET 3.5/3.5 SP1 were incremental add-ons to .NET 2

Answer (score 8):

Everything from 2.0 to 3.5 runs on top of the same version of the .NET run-time so yes, your application will be fine.

Comment: Except for service packs, of course... I believe the 2.0 to 2.0SP1 service pack for the CLR did break *some* things, but very few.

Answer (score 2):

.net 3.0 is basically .net 2.0 plus service pack plus some libraries.

The extra libraries won't hurt, but there are changes in the service pack; you could in theory hit an edge case that makes it not work. So test it.

But usually you are fine.

Comment: Thanks for the good answers all. Well I just tested it on all 3 - 2.0, 3.0 and 3.5 and it was as I expected (and as i have tested it in the past...) - it works...but when I test <3.5, it doesn't work when I write: Using System.Linq; I guess I can reference it...but just to mention it. Other than that, there are no problems...especially considering that the application is at the moment a single file of 2600+ lines of code with 24 assemblies being referenced with "Using...".

Comment: @bill LINQ is 3.5 but you can use it in 2.0 with LinqBridge

Comment: i'll take a note...and...my name isn't "bill"...surprisingly or not :).

Comment: I know that, but I need to mention @bill or it won't light up our message envelope